# Java/Ruby based IMAP proxy library

Tags: java, ruby, imap

I'm looking to create an IMAP proxy to a custom back-end mail and document storage engine and was wondering if there are already any production-ready, stable libraries I can pull on for interacting with the client via IMAP so I just have to write the backend code for mailboxes, listing, retrieving messages, etc.

Answer (score 4):

[James IMAP](http://james.apache.org/imap/) is the Apache IMAP implementation for the [James mail server](http://james.apache.org/) (in Java). I would look at using that as the basis for a solution, since they'll have solved the IMAP implementation issues. In fact it may be worth looking at the whole James project to see what else you can leverage off!

Answer (score 0):

There is no real IMAP-in-a-can library. The best implementation for an IMAP server would be (in my opinion) Dovecot, which you may be able to borrow a number of ideas from.

IMAP in its self is a tricky protocol to implement correctly.